# XSLT is not matching node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm new to XSLT and I'm having issues with a very simple example.

Can someone tell me why this does not match the "Claim" nodes?

I think this should print the word "Claim" for every Claim node, but I've tried several variations of this.

XML

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<ClaimDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.oopfactory.com/2011/XSL/Hipaa">
    <Claim Version="005010X222A1" Type="Professional" TransactionCode="000002866" PatientControlNumber="123456" TotalClaimChargeAmount="206.00" StatementFromDate="2013-08-13">
    </Claim>
</ClaimDocument>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="ClaimDocument">
    <xsl:for-each select="Claim">
      <xsl:text>Claim</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match with the namespace, `http://www.oopfactory.com/2011/XSL/Hipaa`.  Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:hippa="http://www.oopfactory.com/2011/XSL/Hipaa">

    <xsl:template match="/hippa:ClaimDocument">
        <xsl:for-each select="hippa:Claim">
            <xsl:text>Claim</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes.
1. Namespace is missing
2. Initial / is missing for template match

Comment: Yes and No. The first is a mistake but the second is not necessarily a mistake

Comment: Agreed. Mistake is not the right word, but what I wanted to hint was he need make two changes.